# displaying message from console application

Tags: java, swing, awt

How do I pop up message in window from java console application?If I use `JOptionPane`, then I need to pass component which is visible.But if I want to show some warning or error from console application(which does not have any window visible), Then I cant use JOptionPane. Also I want the displayed message to be shown on **top** of any other application(To get the attention of user ).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This way, you render your application useless on headless installations, like unix or linux servers, just for a warning. I would rethink this idea. A console app should stay in the console and just use the console. Maybe you can emit a beep-beep-beep?

Comment: Yes, the ASCII bell would be a better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Message goes here");

EDIT:
```

I tried

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Foo{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Message goes here");
    }
}
```

and the output was

[image]

so your problem could be somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

If you really need a popup, make the component argument null and it will not have a parent.

Comment: if component is null it will not display.

Comment: No, JackMc is correct.  A (non-null) JOptionPane can have a **null parent** and itself display just fine.